# How to delete a substring form a string in c++

Tags: c++, string

Here I have a string like this `WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB` I want to delete all `wub` word form this and get this result `WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND`.
Is there any particular function in c++ to do that I found `string::erase` but that relay doesn't help me!!
I can do that with `for` loop and find this word form string then delete it but I'm looking for better way.
Is there any function to do this???

Comment: You could use `std::regex_replace` ?

Comment: Or `boost::algorithm::replace_all`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace):

```
std::string s1 = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";
std::regex target("(WUB)+");
std::string replacement = " ";
std::string s2 = std::regex_replace(s1, target, replacement);
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ef5651ef7ede617)

Comment: Given the OP's desired output, I think the replacement string should contain a space.

Comment: Ah, and the updated regex replaces consecutive matches with a single space. Good work.

Comment: @Paul R Thanks for your answer it worked prefectly but there should be space between each word in output

Comment: @Daniel.V: I've updated the answer in the last minute or so to fix this - you might need to refresh the page in your browser?

Answer (score 4):

Use boost::algorithm::replace_all

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string input="WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";
    boost::algorithm::replace_all(input, "WUB", " ");
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer to give an example of how this would be applied ?

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful. I guess this wouldn't cope with the OP's example exactly though, i.e. `WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB` -> `WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND` ?

Comment: @PaulR we have to initialize input with "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB" and replacement with "WUB" in place of CD.

Comment: Sure, but the "WUBWUB" between "ARE" and "THE" will give two spaces, not one ?

Comment: @PaulR Yes. I got the point now. regex_replace is the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Erase all occurences:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string removeAll( std::string str, const std::string& from) {
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while( ( start_pos = str.find( from)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.erase( start_pos, from.length());
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {

    std::string s = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";
    s = removeAll( s, "WUB");

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Hg7Kwa

---

Replace all occurences:

```
std::string replaceAll(std::string str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        start_pos += to.length();
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB";
    s = replaceAll( s, "WUB", " ");
    /* replace spaces */
    s = replaceAll( s, "  ", " ");

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Yc8rGv

Comment: From the example in the question it looks like the OP wants to replace one ore more consecutive occurrences of "WUB" with a single space.

Comment: Looks good, except "WUBWUB" should only give one space, I think, not two ?

Comment: Cool: +1 for persistence. :-)